# Adding custom Field To The Posts Listing

Tags: plugins, custom-field, plugin-recommendation, hooks, admin-menu

Are there plugins or hooks to editing custom fields just from the posts listing in admin panel?

Comment: Don't understand what you're wanting to do here.

Comment: For each post in the list of posts in admin panel I see the author, categogory of post, tags, number of comments and the date of publishing. Some of them(category and tags) i could edit by clicking properties of post. Is there posibility to add custom fields for each posts right in the posts listing? This help me don't go into the edit post every time, when I want to change only one custom field. Thanks.

Comment: ok i've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a plugin like [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/). This adds a custom field column to the "Manage Posts" page by default.

Comment: oh, it's exatctly what I want, but for half. The custom fields in the posts listing show up. But it's posible to edit customs fields just for one of the posts, i can't edit custom field for the several posts one time and i need click property. Any idea? anyway thanks, anu!

Comment: just click on quick edit and you can edit the custom fields.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Basically in the "All Posts" listing, I'd like to see one of my custom fields listed. Where can I add this field? (I use the Advanced Custom Fields - ACF)